# Displaying output with strncopy

Tags: c, string

I begin with C and I have to write a method that returns each word in a sentence separated by a whitespace.

So far I have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int nextToken(char const * str, int* from, int* len);

int main(){
    char str[SIZE+1];
    char mot[SIZE+1];

    if(fgets(str, SIZE, stdin) == NULL){
        puts("Error");
        return -1;
    }
    str[SIZE] = '\0';

    int from = 0;
    int len = 0;

    while(nextToken(str, &from, &len)){
        strncpy(mot, &(str[from]), len);
        mot[SIZE] = '\0';
        printf("'%s'\n", mot);
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int nextToken(char const * str, int* from, int* len){
    *from = 1;
    *len = 2;
    return 1;
}
```

I know the return 0 in the while but it's just to run it one time.

So in the `nextToken` function, when changing the value pointed by `len` to 1, I get the expected output for the input hello, i.e `'e'`.

But when changing the value pointed by `len` to 2, I was expecting to get `'el'` but I get `'el¿■('`.

Why do I have this output, why it doesn't print `'el'`?

Sorry if it's stupid but I don't know why this is happening as I begin. I'm compiling in C89.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strncpy` does not copy a null-terminator in case it copies `len` characters. In that eventuality you need to ensure that the string is null-terminated explicitly.

Frankly, I don't think that `strncpy` is really the right function for you to use here.

I'd write it like this:

```
memcpy(mot, str+from, len);
mot[len] = '\0';
```

And you'd want to include a check that this did not result in a buffer overrun.

Comment: This is not what I'm doing with  `mot[SIZE] = '\0';`?

Comment: No, it isn't because `SIZE` is bigger than `len`.

Comment: No it is not. In your program you only copy two characters. The occupy indices 0 and 1. So you'd need a null terminator at index 2.

Comment: @Netch Arg I see it should be `mot[len] = '\0';`. Thanks

Comment: BTW you don't need to use `strncpy`. The latter is devoted specially for filling fixed-size buffers with need to clear possible data leak and/or to compare them. If you know string length exactly, `memcpy` is cheaper and better exposes your intention.

Comment: @Netch I'm now looking at the correction and the teacher used `strncpy`. So I should go with `memcpy` instead?

Comment: If it's for educational purpose, don't mind. They will give the same result.